# How To Update All Tables In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm self learning SQL, using Microsoft Server management and have a question
Let say you have `Customer` table, `Store` table and `Deliver`y table. The store needs to update their stocks count every time a `Customer` purchases a product or a `Delivery`is made(`INSERT INTO TABLE`).
How to update your stock count in `Store` table whenever a data is `Inserted` into `Customer` table and `Delivery` table? And how do you Insert a New product from `Delivery` to your `Store` Table?
I think nested queries is the correct way to do both of these problems but just not sure how to do nested query for `INSERT` query

Comment: You need to use a trigger

Comment: I'm using Microsoft server management to practice

Comment: You might want to look at using a stored procedure to perform all inserts/updates within a transaction for each of your scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not possible to update multiple fields from multiple tables on a single `update` query (depends on your DBMS). You can add triggers, e.g. updating the `Stock` table after an insert on the `Delivery` or `Customer` table. If you want these updates to be done at the exact same time, use a transaction.